# Django db_index in Field что это и зачем?

Tags: django, терминология

Объясните пожалуйста для чего нужен db_index в поле

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
```

Я читал документацию, гуглил и кроме того что `db_index создает индекс в БД` ничего не нашел. В БД и SQL у меня знаний нет, поэтому я и не понимаю значения этого предложения. Если я не буду ставить db_index что изменится? Объясните пожалуйста русским языком :)

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_(%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Comment: Для оптимизации используется https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786413/add-indexes-db-index-true

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 спасибо большое)

Answer (score 5):

Как верно отметили в комментариях, (решил оформить отдельным ответом) используется для ускорения поиска по данным.

Если очень приблизительно - индексы сортируют ваши данные по тому полю, для которого вы укажете `db_index=True`, а искать по сортированным данным получается быстрее, нежели простым перебором всего подряд. Указывайте этот параметр, чтобы создать индекс для поля, по которому вы совершаете поисковые запросы.

Так как индексы хранятся отдельно, их можно создавать для нескольких полей.

Answer (score 0):

индексы достаточно много весят. Выше тебе ответили, как именно ими пользоваться. Лично добавлю от себя, что зачастую с ними нужно работать в полях содержащих INTEGER type. Есть исключения с полями VARCHAR, но это именно, что исключение, чем какая-либо закономерность. Лично я использовал лишь пару раз в VARCHAR type индексы, а именно когда я заведомо знаю, что буду использовать в SELECT - поиск по равенству. Если говорить про этот пример более детально, то использовал в поисковой строке в сайте для блога. Ибо при сортировке по равенству он помогает выполнить запрос куда быстрее. Но точно так же увеличивает вес самой базы данных. Поэтому, пользуйся уж очень аккуратно. Ибо индексы могут точно так же и ухудшить работу твоего сайта.