# django Ошибка при добавлении статьи в базу данных

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Я написал статью, и когда пытаюсь ее сохранить в базу данных, возникает следующая ошибка:

```
OperationalError at /admin/polls/post/5/add/

index row requires 12552 bytes, maximum size is 8191
```

**models.py:**

```
body = RichTextField(blank=True, db_index=True)
```

Можно ли как-то расширить эту индексную строку? Или есть другой способ решения данной проблемы?

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Максимальный размер индксируемого столбца в PostgreSQL составляет **8191** байт. Текст, который вы хотите сохранить в этом поле, *весит* **12552**. Вам действительно нужно индексировать это поле? Это не самая хорошая идея.

Как простое решение, предлагаю, просто удалить параметр `db_index=True` у этого столбца.

Comment: Можете посоветовать статью об этом параметре, когда его следует использовать, а когда нет ?

Comment: Если в кратце, то используйте его, когда часто обращаетесь к этому полю для поиска, выбора данных в таблице. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/976248/django-db-index-in-field-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC

Comment: Только учитывайте, что на изменения в таблицах, в которых используется `db_index`, будет уходить больше времени.

Comment: Все предельно ясно, спасибо